# Is it possible for a .net core app run 2 different GC modes at the same time?

Tags: .net, wpf, garbage-collection, .net-7.0

I have .net 7 WPF app which uses server GC. It has bunch of nugets from 3rd parties. When I run dotTrace I see threads that are server GC AND background GC.. How is it possible?